# Is it possible to regex textarea data in realtime with Pure JS?

Tags: javascript

So this may come across as a little confusing but do try to stick with me. I have the need to regex a single textarea in real time. I do not need any communication with the server I just need all these to be done client side on the fly.

***Context***

The goal is to allow the user to input data like so;

***Apple, Mango, Orange, Banana, Grape***

But as theyre typing I want the client to format the text being typed to,

***Apple | Mango | Orannge | Banana | Grape***

I'm not that versed in Javascript but I can find my way around given enough time. I have attempted something myself which you can see here in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0saa9L0L/5/)

I'm not sure if my thought process is clear to others but I have managed to get the data and regex it, but I'm unsure on how update it in real time in the users textarea.

```
// calculate characters left & position ...
function _set() {
  // Init
  var str = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var regex = new RegExp(',', 'g');

  // replace via regex
  str = str.replace(regex, ' | ');
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = str;
}

print.addEventListener('input', _set);
_set.call(text);
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in a professional way like your project (with RegEx, prototypes and such) but hey it works.

```js
var $textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

$textarea.addEventListener('input',function(){
  $textarea.value = $textarea.value.replace(', ',' | ');
});
```

```css
#textarea{
  width:660px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is an awesome example of what I'm looking for, really stripped back too. Thank you. P.s I'd rather it be stripped back so others behind me can follow along easy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `replace` like this?

```
str.replace(/ \, /g, ' | ');
```

(Replace any comma that has a space before and after with a pipe, before and after)

Comment: More commonly the user will be using a format as such, E.g. Example1, Example2. In your example, E.g. Example , Example ,  The regex will break. However that being said I will be looking to add a safe gaurd in for typos like the formating in your example.